Form array in Angular and ASP.NET
Could someone put me out of my misery? I am desperately trying to understand how a form array of data is sent to an ASP.NET API and ultimately stored in SQL Server.
I can create the Angular form which saves the data to a console. I can also create an API that saves a one to many relationship to a SQL Server table. However I cannot get the two applications to accept the data. And I have yet to find one consistent tutorial or example on the internet that works or does not have all sorts of complicated etc applications that confuse everything.
Would someone be prepared to share some simple source code showing how an Angular form with an array submits data to an ASP.NET API? And what the controller and models should look like on each side. I would be thrilled if I could just get a simple example or get directed to and example or tutorial.
I have used various of the student and grade examples. And the variable relationship options. It appears though that there is no consistency. And as I am a beginner I am confused by all the additional code that get added like MediatR, AutoMapper etc. I know they help but as a basic start I want to just understand the simple code.
